# Prove that number of nonzero elements in inverted matrix is at least 2n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ is invertible matrix $n\times n$  with $ a_{ij} > 0 $ for every $i,j$.
Prove that number of elements that equal to zero in $A^{-1}$  is less or equal to $n^2-2n$. In other words, $A^{-1}$ contains at least $2n$ nonzero elements.

Answer (score 0):

If there were fewer than $2n$ nonzero elements, then there would be a row in $A^{-1}$ with $0$ or $1$ nonzero entries. The former is obviously impossible. Can you also rule out the latter?